# Piecewise Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ denote the periodic function, of period 2, where

$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \cos(\pi x) & 0 < x < 1 \\
      0 &  1 < x < 2 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

and where

$f(0) = \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad f(1) = -\frac{1}{2}$

By referring to the correspondence

$cos(\pi x) $~$ \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4n^2 - 1} \sin(2n\pi x)$

show that

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cos(\pi x) + \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4n^2 - 1} \sin(2n\pi x)$

I am rather lost with this problem. Now, I can see that when $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, the $f(x)$ I am trying to prove resolves to the end point conditions $\frac{1}{2}$ and  $- \frac{1}{2}$. I found it odd that $f(x)$ is effectively $ \frac{1}{2} \cos(\pi x) +  \frac{1}{2} \cos(\pi x)$, but I don't know how to properly argue that for the boundary conditions to be satisfied, then $f(x)$ must be $\frac{1}{2} \cos(\pi x) + \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4n^2 - 1} \sin(2n\pi x)$. I have attempted to solve for $a_n$ and $b_n$, where I changed the integration limits such that they corresponded to $0 < x < 1$ and $1 < x < 2$, but I wasn't able to come to any concrete resolutions for this problem.

Comment: If a function and its derivative are piecewise continuous then the Fourier series converges everywhere to ${ 1 \over 2} (f(x+)+f(x-))$.

Comment: I am honestly shocked by how simple this is. Thank you so much for this!